# Strange behaviour of static readonly variables and collection in C#

Tags: c#, oop, static, readonly

I created a following class within a namespace Global

```
namespace Global
{
    public static class Status
    {
        public static readonly char Active;
        public static readonly char Suspended;
        public static readonly char Terminiated;
        public static readonly char Deleted;

        private static readonly Dictionary<char, string> statusCollection;
        public static Dictionary<char, string> StatusCollection 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return statusCollection; 
            }
        }

        static Status()
        {
            statusCollection = new Dictionary<char, string>();
            statusCollection.Add('A', "Active");
            statusCollection.Add('S', "Suspended");
            statusCollection.Add('T', "Terminated");
            statusCollection.Add('D', "Deleted");

            Active = 'A';
            Suspended = 'S';
            Terminiated = 'T';
            Deleted = 'D';
        }
    }

    public class a
    {
        public void add()
        {
            //How to make this collection readonly
            Status.StatusCollection.Add('N', "asd"); 

            Status.Active = 'M'; //Throws a compile time exception, changes not allowed
        }
    }
}
```

**Strange behaviour** When I tried updating `Status.Active` in immediate window, I was expecting that value won't change but changes were allowed. Does that mean we can change value of `readonly` variable via reflection or runtime ?

Comment: By the way, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-two.aspx) is another treat regarding `readonly` fields, this time in structs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can change the value of a `readonly` property at runtime through Reflection. And here's a very simple POC:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly string Foo = "Bar";

    static void Main()
    {
        typeof(Program)
            .GetField("Foo", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .SetValue(null, "new value");
        Console.WriteLine(Foo);
    }
}
```

When you run this console application it will print:

```
new value
```

Comment: Is it a thread to an application in that case? Does this case applies to constants as well. My belief are that we can't change constants because they are set at compile time and each dll maintains its own copy. Is that true?

Comment: No, this doesn't apply to constants. They are baked at the metadata of the assembly at compile time and you cannot change their value at any possible means, not even with Reflection. As far as your first question whether this is a *thread*, did you mean *threat*? If you meant threat, then it will depend on the situation.